# Python selenium webdriver Chrome - Chrome is being controlled by an automated software

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium webdriver and creating a chrome driver instance. When i try to do scroll down and scroll up,I am getting the following error message. Further I can see an error message 'Chrome is being controlled by an automated software'. Its annoying to see this error though I am not able to change any settings in Chrome browser for allowing automation.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from log_util.logger import log as Log

import time

log = Log()


class Wiki(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.link = 'http://wikipedia.org'
        self.path = '/Users/swadhikar_c/Downloads/chromedriver'
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=self.path)

    def open_wiki(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.link)
        return self.wait_for_page_load()

    def wait_for_page_load(self, timeout=200):
        is_element_located = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'central-featured-logo'))

        try:
            wait(self.driver, timeout=int(timeout)).until(is_element_located)
            print("Page loaded successfully")
            time.sleep(5)
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Operation timed out")
            raise

        return 1

    def scroll_down_up(self):
        driver = self.driver

        element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'html')
        element.send_keys(Keys.END)

        print("Scrolled down to the end!")
        time.sleep(5)

        element.send_keys(Keys.HOME)

        print("Scrolled up to the top!")
        time.sleep(5)

    def close_driver(self):
        self.driver.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wiki = Wiki()

    try:
        if not wiki.open_wiki():
            print("Operation failed")

        wiki.scroll_down_up()

    finally:
        wiki.close_driver()
```

Error message:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/swadhikar_c/pycharm_projects/pyselenium/PySelenium/test/selenium_test.py
>   Page loaded successfully
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/swadhikar_c/pycharm_projects/pyselenium/PySelenium/test/selenium_test.py", line 64, in 
>       wiki.scroll_down_up()
>     File "/Users/swadhikar_c/pycharm_projects/pyselenium/PySelenium/test/selenium_test.py", line 43, in scroll_down_up
>       element.send_keys(Keys.END)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 349, in send_keys
>       'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 249, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot focus element
>     (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461585 (0be2cd95f834e9ee7c46bcc7cf405b483f5ae83b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.4 x86_64)

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image: Chrome Message:]

Comment: "Chrome is being controlled by an automated software" is just a reminder that Chrome is being controlled by another 3rd party software, not an error code. The error should be in your code ([check this issue](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2023/webdriver-api-failed-to-send-keys-because-cannot-focus-element-better-work))

Comment: Agreed but that takes away the focus of the browser from webdriver

Answer (score 4):

I have did some digging and found it resolved. Just modified the init function as below.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def __init__(self):
    self._link = 'https://in.norton.com/'
    _path = '/Users/swadhikar_c/Downloads/chromedriver'
    _chrome_options = Options()
    _chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=_path, chrome_options=_chrome_options)
```