# How to get rid of the infobar "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Been searching for a while and tried all the solutions present but none appear to be working. I created a "slide show" that will first log in, then alternate between tabs. All of that is working but i cannot get rid of the

"Chrome is being controlled by automated test software" bar. Any advise?

Code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
usernameStr = 'test'
passwordStr = 'test'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

#first tab
browser.get(('www.testwebsite.com?'))
# fill in username and hit the next button
username = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)
password = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'password')))
password.send_keys(passwordStr)
nextButton = browser.find_element_by_class_name('emp-submit')
nextButton.click()

#second tab
browser.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', 'tab2');")
browser.switch_to.window("tab2")
browser.get('www.testwebsite.com')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome is being controlled by automated test software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43143014/chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-software)

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409916/python-selenium-webdriver-chrome-chrome-is-being-controlled-by-an-automated-so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open *Chrome Browser* in through *ChromeDriver* this infobar containing the *notification* is embedded as follows:

```
Chrome is being controlled by automated test software
```

- Browser snapshot without the argument `disable-infobars`:

[image: infobar]

But if you add the argument **disable-infobars** through an instance of *ChromeOptions* you can get rid of this infobar as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument('start-maximized')
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
  ```
- Browser snapshot applying the argument `disable-infobars`:

[image: no_infobar]

Comment: This does not work anymore for the latest chromedrivers

Comment: Same as above.  Does not work, using: `Version 87`, `windows10`.

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["enable-automation"])

driver_path = '/Users/myuser/Downloads/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://google.com')

driver.close()
```

Comment: The only one that still works great (Chromedriver for Windows, version 89).

Comment: `options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)`
`options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["enable-automation"])` works and it is the part responsible for the test banner right..... Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your Chrome browser is detecting the Selenium automation process. To get around this, you could use a different driver that is not detected by Chrome. I've included an example below using the [undetected_chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/) module.

Install undetected_chromedriver module # pip install undetected_chromedriver

```
#pip install undetected_chromedriver
import undetected_chromedriver as UC
```

And replace it here

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Now make a driver variable

```
driver = UC.Chrome()
```

When you run this code you will see a chromedriver is generated in the same directory where you work.

It work same thing that this line of code do

```
path = "chromdriver\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
```

Here is an Example:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as UC
driver = UC.Chrome()
driver.get("https:\\www.gmail.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identifierId"]').send_keys("Your Email Address")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identifierNext"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="password"]/div[1]/div / div[1]/input').send_keys("Your Password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="passwordNext"]').click()
print("Login Successfull...!!")
```

Answer (score 1):

THIS IS WORKING WITH LATEST RELEASE.
Try it by changing driver path under "service_obj"

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["enable-automation"])

service_obj = Service(r"C:\Users\Documents\Sublime_srk\drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options,service=service_obj)

driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/")
```

Comment: Your answers could be improved by adding an explanation of the code you supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "x" to close the bar. It doesn't work initially, but then maximize and restore the window and it should disappear. This is for anyone who doesn't trigger their tests through Java.