# selenium not working through proxy in python

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I am writing one script that will have to test sites using selenium. Selenium needs to be able to work with multiple open proxy servers.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
 
 
hostname='165.154.235.188'
port='80'
 
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % hostname + ":" + port)
 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
 
driver.get('https://2ip.ru')
```

I was unable to implement this, when opening the browser writes:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFCYx.png)

Here is what it says in the console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hVW9.png)

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Comment: Can you provide the images at least in a different website? Imgbb doesn't work well for me. Try imgur

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Z9uCZi5

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/iaAEyqF

Comment: It seems that the website is anti-selenium. Try to remove the "This browser is controlled using automated tests". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52614592/how-to-get-rid-of-the-infobar-chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-soft